# google form script exclude sundays on dates choices

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

im making a script for making an apointment. I get the choices of appointmentt date from my spreadsheet using script. How to exclude sunday when i get the choices from my spreadsheet ? i cant find a way to remove the sunday.

here is the code

```
var ssID = "1hil07Z2wvTXH1szX9bNfPKVLDQVO36ACQFGOU6_VUI0";
var formID="1SD5BenAnNxNz-wtw0YPut6YdTf7a62zHn_z3VrTdTUU";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("DATA");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){
var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

labels.forEach(function(label,i){
 var options =  wsData
 .getRange(2, i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
 .getDisplayValues()
 .map(function(o){return o[0]})
 .filter(function(o){return o !== ""})
//Logger.log(options);

updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options);

});

}



function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {
var title = "Tanggal Penjemputan";
var items = form.getItems();
var titles = items.map(function(item){
return item.getTitle();

});
var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
var item = items[pos];
var itemID = item.getId();

updateDropdown(itemID,values);
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {

var item = form.getItemById(id);
item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

this is the form[image]

THis is my spreadsheet
[image]

Comment: Where do your dates come from?

Comment: Some how you need to incorporate Date().getDay() into your selection code.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 from my spreadsheet, i use getDisplayValues from the columns. in the sheet i use =today()+1 so everyday the date changes

Comment: So is this actually a google sheets question about how to get the next week of dates excluding Sunday?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 yes if its possible, i want to get the next day for 1 week excluding sunday

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to achieve your goal:

1. Use a non-Sunday formula in sheet
2. Add a weekday column to sheet and filter in script
3. `getValues` and `new Date` instead of `getDisplayValues`, filter Sunday and then `Utilities.formatDate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```js
=ArrayFormula(TODAY()+FILTER({1;2;3;4;5;6;7}, WEEKDAY(TODAY()+{1;2;3;4;5;6;7})<>1))
```

See on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_2iGV14z-FTmQpf6AkiimshTz6WM7-Ud9LsHY69UlI/edit?usp=sharing)

This will give you the next 7 days excluding Sunday.

Comment: hey bro i tried it but it gives me error :/

Comment: Which error? I cannot help you with such little information. You may need to delete your old formula.